# Write hidden field to sql database php

Tags: php, html, sql, hidden-field

I have these hidden fields which I want to send to my server via the php script. The values of the hidden fields are updated with each keypress event (js):

```
<form action="insert_output.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" id="input_RT" value="">
    <input type="hidden" id="input_cond" value="">
</form>
```

php:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","XXX","pw","dbname");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$rt = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['input_RT']);
$stim = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['input_cond']);
$sql="INSERT INTO `table01` (`rt`, `stim`)
VALUES ('$rt', '$stim')";
if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
echo "1 person's record added";
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

The php script works perfectly with a standard form. Do I have to insert a submit, could this be some "auto-submit" after 10 keypresses?
I have the feeling I'm not too far away from my solution, but please correct me...

Comment: Hidden fields are no different then any other form field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should add name attributes

```
<form action="insert_output.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="input_RT" id="input_RT" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="input_cond" id="input_cond" value="">
</form>
```

and then Simpley get theme in your php script

```
<?php
echo $_POST['input_RT'];
echo $_POST['input_cond'];
?>
```

Comment: It helped that you advised me on the naming issue. That did the trick. Thanks!